# regex to capture string A if there is not string B before next occurrence of string A

Tags: regex

I want to grab text A if there is no text B between it and next occurence of A.
For example, those ones would match

```
A something A something B
^
AAAB
^^
ABAAB
  ^
A B A something
    ^
```

Is it even possible to do? I can't think of any way to do it

Comment: it isn't. i wrote bad examples,I wrote better one now, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use look ahead:

[`A(?=(?:(?!B).)*(?:A|$))`](https://regex101.com/r/tkDYhB/1)

Or with negative look ahead:

[`A(?!(?:(?!A).)*B)`](https://regex101.com/r/H3bJKL/1)

This will work also when `A` or `B` are multi-character strings.

Comment: Updated after your update of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You may want the following regex:

```
A(?![^Aa]*B)
```

It will match any "*A*" which is not followed by any character other than a "*B*".

Check the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/0Lb4Op/1).